# Add form values to variable in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Reactive Form like this :

```
this.editform = new FormGroup({
  'username' :  new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),  
  'password' :  new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),  
  'full_name' :  new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),  
  'avatar' :  new FormControl(null,[Validators.required]),   
});
```

In onSubmit() function, I create a variable named submitValue and pass form value to this varibale:

```
   onSubmit() {
    const submitValue = this.editform.value
    submitValue.username = 'Jon';
    console.log(this.editform.value.username) // Output : 'Jon'  [The value of editform also changed]
  }
```

But whenever I change submitValue value, the editForm value also changed. I only want to get form value from edit form and handle it in submitValue. Is there anyway that I can do it.

Comment: Can you share your html code as well?

Comment: Are you trying some like `const submitValue={...this.editform.value}` (a copy of the object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reference issue, you can deepCopy the reference using any method like

```
const submitValue = Object.assign({},this. editform.value);
```

or

```
const submitValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this. editform.value));
```

or using lodash `cloneDeep` function

Answer (score 2):

```
const submitValue = Object.assign({},this. editform.value);

**Explanation:**
  Whenever we use an assignment operator to assign an object to another variable, it uses pass by reference and maintains it.
```

**Example:**

```
var a = {name: 'abc', age: 12,};
   var b = a;
   b.age = 13;
   console.log(a,b) // you can see a.age is also having 13
```

Now if you use below code

```
var b = Object.assign({}, a);
   b.age = 13
   console.log(a) // This will not change a due to Object.assign()

**Object.assign()**

   Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can create an intermediate `submitValue` object, copying the form's value and overwriting parts of it:

```
const submitValue = { ...this.editform.value, username = 'Jon' };
```